# Making 3D or 2D Modelling and Drawings

Tags: drawing, modeling, maya, autodesk

I need some pictures for my site like this;

```
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8014/7490668848_a800ec5337_b.jpg
https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7270/7769969514_acd8dcf948_b.jpg
```

How can I draw pictures like this? I need help very much

Comment: Hello, Stackoverflow is a programming Q&A site, as your question is not related to programming it will be closed as being off-topic. I'd recommend you to check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) what kind of questions are on topic.

Comment: In the meantime, based on your question, you seem to be a beginner in the world of 3D modelling. I'd also recommend you to take some courses about Maya. You can find these on many websites on the internet: [Creative Crash](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/tutorials/), [Digital Tutors](http://digitaltutors.com/software/Maya-tutorials), [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/Maya-training-tutorials/255-0.html), [Simply Maya](http://simplymaya.com/autodesk-maya-training/free-tutorials/?cat_id=23) and many others.

Comment: As a last advice, before doing your real project (modelling a castle or many characters), lower your expectations. Modeling, Rigging, Texturing, Animating, FX, Lighting... and other departments require A LOT of time and experience and you'll only be able to master one or two of them depending on your skills and preferences. First of all, do basic tutorials, then increase the size and the complexity of the assets you are creating (the first asset I made was a coffee grinder). Good luck in your training and never give up, you'll fail a lot and your first assets will look bad, that's normal.